# How to handle null pointer exception in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make photo gallery application.But I am having following error and my program will crashed.Also I am having error to this line :

```
imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
```

error

```
09-03 16:45:22.618: E/AndroidRuntime(443): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-03 16:45:22.628: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 16:45:22.628: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.example.myfirstapplication.setwall$1.onItemClick(setwall.java:40)
09-03 16:45:22.648: E/dalvikvm(443): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.sai.samples.views;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GalleryView extends Activity {
    Integer[] pics = {
            R.drawable.antartica1,
            R.drawable.antartica2,
            R.drawable.antartica3,
            R.drawable.antartica4,
            R.drawable.antartica5,
            R.drawable.antartica6,
            R.drawable.antartica7,
            R.drawable.antartica8,
            R.drawable.antartica9,
            R.drawable.antartica10
    };
    ImageView imageView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "You have selected picture " + (arg2+1) + " of Antartica", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);

            }

        });

    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
            ta.recycle();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,120));
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            return iv;
        }

    }
}
```

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post the _relevant_ part (setwall$1.onItemClick)

Comment: did you tried to debug your code? ... imageView is null, i think ...

Comment: what is the line which logcat pointing onItemClick(setwall.java:40)

Comment: @kaluwila at imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]); this line I am having error.

Comment: your code should work please clean and run again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line probably returns null :

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
```

Check if the `ImageView` id is correct, and try to clean and rebuild your project if the error persists.

Comment: Are you sure? The listener is added to the gallery, not the `ImageView`.

Comment: @Dalmas I dont understand what exactly you are saying.Please explain

Comment: I mean it's very likely that there isn't an `ImageView` with the id `ImageView01` in your `main.xml` file.

Comment: Can you post your `main.xml` file?

Comment: @Dalmas I have posted the main.xml file

Comment: That's stange, I don't understand how your code can throw a NullPointerExcception. Don't forget to clean and rebuild your project. If it still doesn't work, try to know which variable is null in your code.

Comment: @Dalmas how to  clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: In Eclipse: "Project" > "Clean" then try to run it again.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code for creating a gallery of images,

```
public class GalleryViewActivity extends Activity 
{

    GridView gridView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);

           gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}


class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    ArrayList<String> images;

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else 
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
           imageView.setClickable(true);

           imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), showImageClass.class);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mThumbIds.toString() + " Clicked", 5000).show();
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("imageName", mThumbIds[position]);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
//         imageView.setImageDrawable(images);
//         imageView.setImageBitmap(images);
//         imageView.setImageResource(images[]);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

//     references to images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
            R.drawable.abc,
            R.drawable.def,
            R.drawable.klm, 
            R.drawable.pqr,
            R.drawable.rst, 
            R.drawable.wxy,
            R.drawable.xyz, 
    };
}
```

Comment: I want to show all images in only that activity.In this code you have added showImageClass.So I dont want to do that.can you please change this code?

Comment: Have you used this code. This code is to show gallery type view of Images, where all images are shown that are in drawable folder. showImage class is created to show large view of the image. whenever you click on any of the image from gallery view, 'showImage' class is called to show large view of the image clicked.

Comment: I am able to see gallery images only when I am clicking on it for showing large view it is stop working.

Comment: I am posting my code for showing both the gallery view and the large image.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class GalleryViewActivity

```
public class GalleryViewActivity extends Activity 
{

    GridView gridView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}


class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    ArrayList<String> images;

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else 
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
           imageView.setClickable(true);

           imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), showImageClass.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("position", "" + position);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

//     references to images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
            R.drawable.abc,
            R.drawable.def,
            R.drawable.klm, 
            R.drawable.pqr,
            R.drawable.rst, 
            R.drawable.wxy,
            R.drawable.xyz, 
    };
}
```

Dont forget to add images in the `drawable` folder. the image should be same as you mentioned in the `mThumbIds` array, like i have used abc.jpg, def.jpg and so on..
Then you need to create a `showImage.java` class, here you take a imageview to show the large view of image clicked..

```
public class showImageClass extends Activity
{
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
            R.drawable.abc,
            R.drawable.def,
            R.drawable.klm, 
            R.drawable.pqr,
            R.drawable.rst, 
            R.drawable.wxy,
            R.drawable.xyz, 
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showimage);
        int position = Integer.parseInt(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("position"));
        ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        jpgView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }
}
```

This code has worked for me, it will definitely work..
Dont forget to add the relavent images and import the class libraries that are needed.
Mention both the activities in android manifest file